# php query string header

Tags: php, redirect

Hello I have a problem with `header('Location: http://www.example2.com/');` while there is a query string.

Ok I will make the question easy to understand:

now I have a domain name `http://example1.com/?url=url` I want when someone want to access example1.com it redirects him to example2.com but if he types example1.com/?url=url nothing will happen so how can I do that please and thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `if (count($_GET) > 0) { ... }` if you want to check if the request has *any* parameters.

Answer (score 1):

What do you use for redirecting? From your post's first line I assume, that you're redirecting the user via the PHP `header` function. So, check in PHP whether there is a query string or not:

```
<?php
if (empty($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]))
{
    header("Location:  http://www.example2.com/");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have index.php in root directory of domain `example1.com`. And you can use this;

```
<?php

if (empty($_GET["url"])) {
    header("Location:  http://www.example2.com/");
}
```

Comment: thankssss aloooooooottt I love you I forgot about this code :p